# Deployment web-application on application server. Database access credentials

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application which I deploy on Tomcat Server manually.

My property file with database credentials is not located in classpath. On startup I load it like this:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\application.property"));
```

Downback of this is that now I can move my code to linux based platform without changing the source.

If I put this file to classpath it will be packed inside war (with all credentials) and replaced every time I redeploy my application. Tomcat is deleting application dir and replace it with war content on redeploy.

The question is: How and where to put property file in classpath and ensure that this file will not be replaces/deleted by application server on application redeployment. And the file must not be inside war.

Answer (score 2):

The thing which you are doing looks like anti-pattern. Do not store database connection credentials in external `property` file.

Database access credentials should be placed inside `context.xml` configuration file of your tomcat. This is called JNDI Resources and you can read about it, for example, [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).